# Adjust the location and size of beamer's framebox for a custom theme

Tags: beamer, boxes, themes

I am trying to create a simple custom beamer theme for presentations by my lab at school.

Our department has a relatively nice powerpoint theme as shown below which I have for the most part successfully replicated in beamer using

```
%\newlength{\myheight}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth, \the\paperheight);
        \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor = north west] (header) at (0,\the\paperheight) 
            {\includegraphics[width=\the\paperwidth,trim=0.01in 9.05in 3.15in 0.45in, clip]{WVU-Pattern-Thin-295-Coated}};
        \node[inner sep=2pt,anchor = north west] (wvlogo) at ($(0.025*\the\paperwidth,0.97*\the\paperheight)$)
            {\includegraphics[width=0.3\paperwidth]{Engineering-FL-124andWhite}};
            \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor = west] (website) at ($(0.765*\the\paperwidth,0.888*\the\paperheight)$)
            {\hypersetup{colorlinks=false} \fontseries{m} \fontfamily{phv} \tiny \selectfont \color{white} \href{http://www.statler.wvu.edu}{www.statler.wvu.edu}};
        %\global\settoheight\myheight{\includegraphics[width=\the\paperwidth,trim=0.01in 9.05in 3.15in 0.45in, clip]{WVU-Pattern-Thin-295-Coated}}
        %\global\advance\textheight by-\myheight
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

where the images represent the background and logos.
[image: the powerpoint layout]

Now everything is working decently well (at least for me and my labmates to use) but I would like to tell beamer to shrink the frame boxes to only include the area beneath that header that will show up on every frame (except for plain frames which I still need to implement)(i.e. I want the text/titles/footers/etc to show up in the white space).

Is there some way to do this?  I've tried messing with shrinking `\textheight` as can be seen in the commented portions of my code but the framebox just shrinks in this case and still starts at the top.  I need some way to shrink it and offset from the top and I haven't been able to figure out how to do this by looking at the beamer class file.  As I write this I am thinking maybe the issue is that I should define this as a header rather than a background although I'm not entirely sure how to deal with the tikzpicture in this case.

You can find my code with a minimum example posted [here](https://bitbucket.org/aliounis/wvubeamer) which can be compiled using pdflatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the idea I had about making this a header and not a background was the correct one.

Basically I took the code that I had in the background template and instead put it in the headline template (ad got rid of the boundingbox line from the tikz picture.

I will leave this question up for the time being to see if anyone else has any creative solutions and if no one else answers I will delete it.